# Bring Java Console to Front of Screen

Tags: java, console

I have a java application that works just in console (windows command prompt for example). I would like to occasionally bring the window to the front screen. Is there something that I can add to my code to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using awt or swing, then both `Window` and `JFrame` have `toFront()` method to bring the window to the front. If you are using console, I don't think that's possible.